# The eigenvectors of $A$ are also of $A^\ast$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix. If $\alpha$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $\alpha$ is an eigenvector of its adjugate matrix $A^\ast$.

Since $AA^\ast=A^\ast A=|A|E$. If $A\alpha=\lambda\alpha$, we have 
$$
AA^\ast\alpha=A^\ast A\alpha=\lambda A^\ast\alpha=|A|\alpha.
$$

If $|A|\ne0$, $\alpha$ is an eigenvector of $A^\ast$.

If $|A|=0$, but $\lambda\ne0$, we have $A^\ast\alpha=0$, which implies $\alpha$ is also an eigenvector of $A^\ast$.

Now suppose $|A|=0,\;\lambda=0$, then how to prove $\alpha$ is also an eigenvector of $A^\ast$?

Comment: The zero vector is never an eigenvector, so you do not need to consider the case $\alpha=0$. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $A^*\alpha=\frac 1\lambda|A|\alpha$, so the only problematic case is $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @csch2 I suspect "$\ \alpha=0\ $" in the last sentence is a typo for "$\ \lambda=0\ $."

Comment: Sorry my false. It should be "$\lambda=0$".

Comment: Whatis $|A|$ and what is $E$? Determinant and identity matrix?

Comment: Yes. $|A|=\det A$, and $E=\text{diag}(1,\cdots,\,1)$.

Comment: Quite unusual notation, but ok.

Comment: If $\alpha\in\operatorname{im}(A)$, then fine because $A^*A=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest proof is to note that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$.

For an alternative proof, note that

- $\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)A^{-1}$ when $A$ is nonsingular,
- $\operatorname{adj}(A)=uv^T$ for when $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-1$, where $u$ and $v$ are some nonzero vectors in respectively the right and the left null spaces of $A$,
- $\operatorname{adj}(A)=0$ when $\operatorname{rank}(A)<n-1$.

The statement in question is evidently true in the first and the third case. In the second case, suppose $(\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair of $A$. If $\lambda\ne0$, then $\operatorname{adj}(A)x=\operatorname{adj}(A)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}Ax\right)$. If $\lambda=0$, then $x$ is a scalar multiple of $u$.

Comment: $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is *entrywise* a polynomial of the entries of $A$. I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @amsmath $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$. If $f$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $\operatorname{adj}(A)=q(A)$, where $q$ is the polynomial $q(x)=(-1)^n\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that, sorry.

Comment: Why $x$ is a scalar multiple of $adj(A)$ when $\lambda=0$?

Comment: @Xie The burden of proof is on you. Hint: $A$ has rank $n-1$ and its (right) null space is spanned by $u$.

Comment: @user1551: I have seen that the columns of $\text{adj}A$ are solutions of $Ax=0$. Now I doubt if $(\text{adj}A)x=0$ , since $uv^\top u$ may not equal $0$.

Comment: @Xie Hmm, why would you want it to be zero? You are asked to prove that $x$ is an eigenvector of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$, not that $x$ is an eigenvector of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ *corresponding to the zero eigenvalue*.